# How can I host my React application using GitHub?

Tags: reactjs, github

I have created my React project and pushed the complete repo to GitHub using Visual Studio Code. How can I make my React project live on server with the help of GitHub?

Comment: You can serve the build outputs of a typical React project using GitHub Pages. Here's one I made earlier: https://github.com/textbook/abv (CRA app -> GitHub Actions -> GitHub Pages). Whether that's going to work for your specific case is unclear.

Comment: Refer this below link:
https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f

Comment: Thank you very much for the references. I will go through them and reachout to you for the progress

Answer (score 3):

You need to install GitHub Pages package as a dev-dependency.

```
cd ./into/your-app-folder
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
```

Add properties to package.json file.

The first property you need to add at the top level homepage, second you must define this as a string and the value will be "https://{your-username}.github.io/{repo-name}" , {repo-name} is the name of the GitHub repository you created it will look like this :

```
"homepage": "http://joedoe.github.io/his-app"
```

Second in the existing scripts property you need to add predeploy and deploy.

```
"scripts": {
//...
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```

If you pushed everything already to Github, the last step is deploying.
One liner:

```
npm run deploy
```

With this Github will create a new branch called gh-pages, and will be available online. Hope I could help and will work accordingly.

If you stuck, you can look it up on the **official docs of React**.
[Deployment Documentation of React](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)

*Once on a deployment I had some issues with the official documentation, and I had to delete my username from the "homepage" property in order to make it work. Although I suggest you first do by the docs, and if you encounter problems, you might can give a try.*

Comment: If you're using react-router you have to use hashHistory instead of HTML5 history API. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing

Answer (score 0):

with the latest version of `create-react-app` you can use empty `homepage` parameter in `package.json`

> {...
> "homepage" = "",
> ...}

Answer (score -1):

There are several options. Depends on what you want to do, do you want to deploy for production or just to test your development ?

You have several options to deploy such as Heroku, Netlify, Github pages.

I can help you with the process of deploying, in addition you can have a look on the different documentations for the solutions listed above.

I personnaly suggest using Netlify, in my opinion realy easy to use.

Depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I dont get why my answer is getting downvoted OP didn't state he wanted to use Github pages. He only stated "with help of Github". Wich can be achieved with hooks in the services i listed above. Be more precise if you want to use a specific hosting provider.